# Update UI for all ViewControllers using inheritance

Tags: ios, swift

I've an BaseViewController from which I have inherited 2 ViewControllers. Both of them have a small player section, and depending on type of music I want to update that UI.

So I've kept the code in the BaseViewController and it is invoked via a Notification that I trigger from one of the inherited ViewControllers

But the problem I'm facing is, that the UI wont update correctly and the image never loads and also the sometimes the text fields wont be update as well.

```
func updatePlayerViewWithLiveDetails() {
    guard let user = SWMusicManager.sharedInstance.liveUser else { return }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.bottomView.liveSharedBy.text = "Shared by \(user.username ?? "")"
        if let followersCount = user.followers {
            self.bottomView.liveListenersLabel.text = String(describing: followersCount)
        }
    }
    if let profilePictureURL = user.profilePictureUrl {
        SWServiceController().downloadImageFrom(profilePictureURL, completion: { (success, data) in
            if success {
                guard let imageData = data else { return }
                guard let image = UIImage(data: imageData) else { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    self?.bottomView.profileImageView.image = image
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Is there a way how I can resolve this.

EDIT 1: I know that the code gets executed twice because it has been inherited twice and is present in the tab-controller.

Comment: Can you make a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  There's not really anything here to go on.

Comment: did you check that it goes past `SWMusicManager.sharedInstance.liveUser` ? maybe there is a problem there. Also, could you explain the class hierarchy with a sketch maybe? it would be easier to understand what you mean